# .simulate("click") not working with Clearbox JS in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, prototypejs

I am trying to use [ClearBox JS](http://www.clearbox.hu/) to open an overlay onload, but my solutions don't seem to work in Google Chrome.

using simulate from [protolicious](https://github.com/kangax/protolicious/blob/5b56fdafcd7d7662c9d648534225039b2e78e371/event.simulate.js)

```
<body onload="clickNameChange();">

function clickNameChange() {
  $("name_change_button").simulate("click");
}

<a id="name_change_button" href="/name_change.htm" rel="clearbox[width=600,,height=400]">Opener()</a>
```

I have the current window replaced with the content in my link instead of the ClearBox overlay opening as it does in FF and IE.

Alternate solutions tried:

```
document.getElementById("name_change_button").onclick();

triggerEvent($("name_change_button"), "click");

function triggerEvent(element, eventName) {
  // safari, webkit, gecko
  if (document.createEvent)
  {
    var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    evt.initEvent(eventName, true, true);

    return element.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }

  // Internet Explorer
  if (element.fireEvent) {
    return element.fireEvent('on' + eventName);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't possible to fix this. After showing the clearbox JS dev a demo-site he couldn't resolve it.
So I ended up running with a much simpler solution like this:
http://weblogs.asp.net/jeff/archive/2006/10/25/Modal_2D00_style-pops-in-Javascript-and-CSS.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`$("name_change_button")` should be `$("#name_change_button")`, shouldn't it?

Also wondering why you need to open the overlay by simulating the button click -- I don't know much about ClearBox, but how does your code run the necessary JavaScript to open the overlay? I don't see anything in the anchor element that (as I understand it) would do anything other than open /name_change.htm.

Comment: The # shouldn't be there, maybe you're thinking of jquery? I am simulating a click because I need the link which clearbox uses to be clicked onload();

Comment: OK -- thought you were using jQuery. But (sorry if I'm missing something) what is in the anchor element code that will call JavaScript when clicked -- does ClearBox rewrite this element? Also, can you open the overlay directly, avoiding the need to simulate the click?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I found in the sparce documentation a workaround where I can directly call the function:     CB_Open('href=/name_change.htm,,width=600,,height=350'); but it still doesn't work in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to open clearbox on page load by setting GET parameter to url:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
echo "<script>$(window).load(function () {
CB_Open('href=mymodal.php?id=".$_GET['id'].",,width=700,,height=700');
});
</script>
";
}
```

Requires: PHP/jQuery/Clearbox.js

Enjoy!